# I don't understand the code related to RNN

Tags: tensorflow

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

tf.set_random_seed(777)  # reproducibility

sentence = ("if you want to build a ship, don't drum up people together to "
            "collect wood and don't assign them tasks and work, but rather "
            "teach them to long for the endless immensity of the sea.")

char_set = list(set(sentence))
char_dic = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(char_set)}

data_dim = len(char_set)
hidden_size = len(char_set)
num_classes = len(char_set)
sequence_length = 10  # Any arbitrary number
learning_rate = 0.1

dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, len(sentence) - sequence_length):
    x_str = sentence[i:i + sequence_length]
    y_str = sentence[i + 1: i + sequence_length + 1]
    print(i, x_str, '->', y_str)

    x = [char_dic[c] for c in x_str]  # x str to index
    y = [char_dic[c] for c in y_str]  # y str to index

    dataX.append(x)
    dataY.append(y)

batch_size = len(dataX)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length])

# One-hot encoding
X_one_hot = tf.one_hot(X, num_classes)
print(X_one_hot)  # check out the shape



def lstm_cell():
    cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
    return cell

multi_cells = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(2)], state_is_tuple=True)

# outputs: unfolding size x hidden size, state = hidden size
outputs, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_cells, X_one_hot, dtype=tf.float32)

# FC layer
X_for_fc = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, hidden_size])
outputs = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(X_for_fc, num_classes, activation_fn=None)

# reshape out for sequence_loss
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [batch_size, sequence_length, num_classes])

# All weights are 1 (equal weights)
weights = tf.ones([batch_size, sequence_length])

sequence_loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(
    logits=outputs, targets=Y, weights=weights)
mean_loss = tf.reduce_mean(sequence_loss)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(mean_loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(500):
    _, l, results = sess.run(
        [train_op, mean_loss, outputs], feed_dict={X: dataX, Y: dataY})
    for j, result in enumerate(results):
        index = np.argmax(result, axis=1)
        print(i, j, ''.join([char_set[t] for t in index]), l)

# Let's print the last char of each result to check it works
results = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: dataX})
for j, result in enumerate(results):
    index = np.argmax(result, axis=1)
    if j is 0:  # print all for the first result to make a sentence
        print(''.join([char_set[t] for t in index]), end='')
    else:
        print(char_set[index[-1]], end='')

'''
0 167 tttttttttt 3.23111
0 168 tttttttttt 3.23111
0 169 tttttttttt 3.23111
…
499 167  of the se 0.229616
499 168 tf the sea 0.229616
499 169   the sea. 0.229616

g you want to build a ship, don't drum up people together to collect wood and don't assign them tasks and work, but rather teach them to long for the endless immensity of the sea.

'''
```

(Please understand that English is not my native language)

I don't understand the last 'if, else' part of the code above, can anyone explain?

Why do print(''. Join ([char_set [t] for t in index]), end = '') only when j is 0,

In the case of else, why do print(char_set [index [-1]], end = '')?

Please explain how the code works

Answer (score 1):

That last bit is just checking whether the network works or not. It generates multiple results first, and then iterates through those results. I guess the creator of this code snippet wanted to check the whole sentence in the first result, and then only the last characters for the rest. That is up to you entirely, if you want to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how does print (char_set [index [-1]], end = '') work? I don't know what index [-1] means

Comment: Python allows negative indices too and they start indexing from the back. So [-1] means the last element of the array "index".
The char_set array I assume is the possible characters in a sentence, and the network outputs indices in this char_set (these are contained in array "index"). Selecting the last element of the output (index[-1]) gives an index in char_set, so you get the last character in the sentence by char_set[index[-1]]